# Angular JS, Directives Not Displaying DATA

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

*Fairly new to ANGULAR!!*

I have created a "directive" named "contactCard". What I'm trying to achieve with the help of this directive to display some json Data. But unfortunately data is not getting displayed.

[**[WORKING CODES ARE PLACED HERE ON PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/DAUkixDSOvjBKGhYjAu3?p=preview)**]

I have this html:

```
<ul class="digi-alert-list" ng-controller="jsonNotify">
    <li ng-repeat="notifications in notify">
        <contact-card data="notifications"></contact-card>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And MainAPP file:

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module("MainApp", 
  ["ui.bootstrap","app.directives.contactCard"]
);
app.controller('jsonNotify', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('notification.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.notify = res.data;                
        });
});
})();
```

Finally contactCard.js

```
angular.module('app.directives.contactCard', [])
    .directive('contactCard', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '='
            },

            template: '<div class="alert-report"><p>{{notifications.serveactivity}}</p></div>',
            controller: function($scope){
                alert("directives");
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: shouldn't it be data.serveractivity in the directive template,.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ILQOFAgaXE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are binding "data" in your scope to notifications, but you are using "notifications" in your directive template.

Your directive template should be:

```
template: '<div class="alert-report"><p>{{data.serveactivity}}</p></div>',
```

Answer (score 2):

If you declare that `data` is the variable on your scope, like you did here:

```
scope: {
    data: '='
},
```

Then in your template, you have to use `data`, and not `notifications`:

```
template: '<div class="alert-report"><p>{{data.serveactivity}}</p></div>',
```

When you declare your scope like this, it means that it's an "Isolated Scope". It knows only the variables you declared for it. It has no knowledge of the outside world.

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object).